# How to remove the gap after spanning columns in grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

I was trying to do a shape using grid instead of flex and that is to make the first article span two columns and the other two article be under the first article, when i spanned the two columns a gap showed up between the second and third article elements, here's the code below, please help.

**html** `

```
<main class="single-price-grid">
    <article class="single-price white" >
      <h3>Join our community</h3>
      <h5>  30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee
      </h5>
      <p>  Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. 
        Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.
      </p>
    </article>
    <article class="single-price blue">
      <h3>  Monthly Subscription</h3>
      <span> &dollar;29</span><span>per month</span>
      <p>
        Full access for less than &dollar;1 a day
      </p>
      <button class="btn">Sign Up</button>
    </article>
    <article class="single-price pale-blue">
      <h3>Why Us</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Tutorials by industry experts</li>
        <li>Peer &amp; expert code review</li>
        <li>Coding exercises</li>
        <li>Access to our GitHub repos</li>
        <li>Community forum</li>
        <li>Flashcard decks</li>
        <li>New videos every week</li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </main>
```

`

**Css** `

```
body {
    background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

.single-price-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.single-price-grid .single-price {
    box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;

}
.single-price-grid .white {
    grid-column: span 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`

Comment: remove margin: 0 auto from
```
.single-price-grid .white {
    grid-column: span 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: if you got this type of problem don't forget to use inspect tool

Answer (score 0):

remove `margin: 0 auto` from
`.single-price-grid .white { grid-column: span 2; margin: 0 auto; }`